# 'module' object has no attribute 'draw_all'

Tags: python-3.x, drawnow

I am trying to use drawnow to plot a graph using python.
but there is always an error says that "drawnow has no attribute to draw-all"

I'm using python 3 and the latest version of drawnow

Thank you for your help!

```
import serial # import Serial Library
import numpy  # Import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
from drawnow import *

tempF= []
pressure=[]
arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1451', 9600) #Creating our serial object named arduinoData
plt.ion() #Tell matplotlib you want interactive mode to plot live data
cnt=0

def makeFig(): #Create a function that makes our desired plot
    plt.ylim(80,90)                                 #Set y min and max values
    plt.title('My Live Streaming Sensor Data')      #Plot the title
    plt.grid(True)                                  #Turn the grid on
    plt.ylabel('Temp F')                            #Set ylabels
    plt.plot(tempF, 'ro-', label='Degrees F')       #plot the temperature
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')                    #plot the legend
    plt2=plt.twinx()                                #Create a second y axis
    plt.ylim(93450,93525)                           #Set limits of second y axis- adjust to readings you are getting
    plt2.plot(pressure, 'b^-', label='Pressure (Pa)') #plot pressure data
    plt2.set_ylabel('Pressrue (Pa)')                    #label second y axis
    plt2.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)           #Force matplotlib to NOT autoscale y axis
    plt2.legend(loc='upper right')                  #plot the legend


while True: # While loop that loops forever
    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #Wait here until there is data
        pass #do nothing
    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline() #read the line of text from the serial port
    dataArray = arduinoString.split(',')   #Split it into an array called dataArray
    temp = float( dataArray[0])            #Convert first element to floating number and put in temp
    P =    float( dataArray[1])            #Convert second element to floating number and put in P
    tempF.append(temp)                     #Build our tempF array by appending temp readings
    pressure.append(P)                     #Building our pressure array by appending P readings
    drawnow(makeFig)                       #Call drawnow to update our live graph
    plt.pause(.000001)                     #Pause Briefly. Important to keep drawnow from crashing
    cnt=cnt+1
    if(cnt>50):                            #If you have 50 or more points, delete the first one from the array
        tempF.pop(0)                       #This allows us to just see the last 50 data points
        pressure.pop(0)
```

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: code is added..

Comment: The code does not invoke `draw_now` anywhere (and it's a `pyplot`'s method anyway). Can we please see the stacktrace?